# Why expression inside map() function executed only when using count() function?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When I use `count()` function "inside test" message called three times as expected but when I remove `count(`) function call `test()` function doesn't called. From `count()` function documentation I understand that it returns the count of elements in given stream.

```
public class Start {
    public static int test(int input) {
        System.out.println("inside processRecord");
        return input;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        data.parallelStream().map(Start::test).count();
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about terminal  operations: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `count` is a terminal operation, and streams are invoked/executed only when a terminal one is present; they are said to be lazy...

Just notice that in java-9 and above, your example would not print those statements from `map` either way, since all you care about is *how many* and `map` is sort of useless...

Answer (score 0):

Intermediate operations (like map) return a stream and are being invoked by terminal operations that return non-stream values.